# Edit Text in Visio 2016 (.vsdx) by utilizing the 'Find & Replace' functionality or doing so with code in python

Tags: python, visio

I am pretty new to Python, and I am trying to add some code to a project that will automatically update a location name on a Visio map when it is changed in a program I developed.

Essentially, when a location name is changed in the program, I want it to find the original location name and replace it with the new location name, which would both be defined strings, and save the Visio file so that it stays updated and shows changes when opened.

Anyone know of a way to do this or some libraries that would be useful? I found some examples after a quick google search but they all are very outdated.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone was trying to do this in Perl 12.5 years ago: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=127.0

Comment: Looks like it's not possible using COM: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/cb4f6170-cf98-4c03-aa14-233d55ec6639/find-and-replace-text?forum=visiogeneral

Comment: `.vsdx` is `xml` so perhaps you can modify it directly.

Comment: Or you could automate the Visio GUI. There are probably 5 different popular ways of doing that in Python.

Comment: @PeterWood Could you point me in the right direction for these popular ways you speak of?

Comment: What have you found by searching? I don’t want to recommend anything, just choose one and try it.